Witten anomaly and product representation
The Witten anomaly restricts the number of fermion doublets in an $SU(2)$ theory.
If we have a gauge group $SU(2)_1 \times SU(2)_2$ and have only one fermion fundamental $\psi = (2,2)$, is this theory Witten anomaly-free?
The reason that I think so is that there are two $SU(2)_1$ doublets because each component of $SU(2)_2$ doublet has one $SU(2)_1$ doublet attached to it and vice versa.
Is this logic correct?

Note that this is just SO(4) with a vector. This is indeed anomaly-free -- your argument is correct, and a different one is that vectors are real, so they admit symmetric mass terms.
